# Show 3 significant figures for rep over a million

Tags: feature-request, reputation, unicoins, fun, information-display

With "reputation to the max" I now have 6,621,210 reputation. Unfortunately, this only shows as 6.6m:

[image: Mucho rep]

Other reputation levels are shown with three or more significant digits - e.g. 508k as Darin's rep shows above, or *xx.x*k for values in the [10k, 100k), or the exact value for under 10k.

Why the discrimination against users with over a million rep? Why not show 6.62m?

Comment: You don't know the half of it; I am *still* listed bottom right instead of top left, my 2.3 million should trump your measly 662k.. hey.. wait a second!

Comment: Sounds like a first world problem.

Comment: #johnskeetproblems

Comment: It would be an atrocity for some ignorant nay-sayer to think that you only have 6,550,000 rep when you really have 6,649,999 rep. We can't slight the pillar of our rep community by 100k.

Comment: Nice one! Almost bit.

Comment: Never enough ey?

Comment: Interestingly enough Stack Exchange already support the `m`. Is this a sign to upvote Jon?

Comment: In all seriousness, should be tagged `[bug]` as well, **m** is for *milli-*, x/1000, **M** is for *mega-*, 1000000x.

Comment: @NickT: You could raise that separately. While I agree with the sentiment, it doesn't bother me on a *practical* basis.

Comment: What page is that overview? I don't know any that sums of rep over all sites.

Comment: @Fabian: On the "network account" page. Here's mine, for instance: https://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet?tab=reputation

Comment: No, that's just the reputation graph that compares all accounts. I mean the picture in this question that compares different users and shows you with 6.6M. Also, I just noticed: Where does that number even come from? Even with all your accounts combined, you don't have 6 million reputation. Is this a counter as if there was no daily reputation maximum?

Comment: @Fabian: It was April 1st - I assume that the 2014 April Fool joke was reputation-based. (I don't remember it offhand.)

Answer (score 84):

Sorry, but you're making a false assumption here. The "m" is not for "millions" (that would be "M"), but for morpfloggles. One morpfloggle is 1,003,214. Thus you have precisely 6.6m rep, to the 5th digit. We're just not displaying trailing zeros.

Comment: I can haz first result on https://www.google.com/search?q=morpfloggle?

Comment: [That was some pretty quick indexing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5SlgU.png)

Comment: So: word made up at `2014-04-01 19:03:39Z`. Search link posted at `2014-04-01 19:04:13Z` (34 seconds later). Pictoral evidence posted at  `2014-04-01 19:14:19Z` (10m40s later). At what point did the result actually appear?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn It was crawled at 19:09:49 according to http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F227898%2Fshow-3-significant-figures-for-rep-over-a-million&oq=cache%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F227898%2Fshow-3-significant-figures-for-rep-over-a-million

Comment: Six minutes and ten seconds: not bad at all, Mr. Google.

Comment: You measure temperature in Fahrenheits, distance in yards, height in toes, volume in barrels, area in towels, so it's quite logical you won't count in metrical units ^^

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ I'm German. I do none of those horrible things.

Comment: What's the German word for *pleasure derived by someone at the cumbersome measuresome units of others*?

Comment: @kojiro Exotenmaßergötzen

Comment: @toscho that's astoundingly apt.