# Shouldn't "mviews" actually be "Mviews"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, views

Since the `m` in `mviews` supposedly stands for [mega-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega-) as in the [International System of Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) it should be abbreviated with a capital M as `Mviews`.

Unless I'm misunderstanding it, and those are milli-views :-)

Comment: You are clearly misunderstanding it. ["m" stands for morpfloggles, which is 1,003,214](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227920), and is definitely correct.

Comment: views are not an ISO unit (neither are bytes, kibibyte advocates! :P)

Comment: Given that one-thousandth of a view is meaningless, I'm guessing everyone understands it, and you've found something even more pedantic to point out than a pluralization bug. This is innovation. Congratulations!

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't stand for "mega". It stands for "million" and then we used to place the "m" in a somewhat weird location. [This is no longer a thing we do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232137/155160), so here we are. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) :)

Comment: Well, arguably since we switched `t` --> `k` then we are using a form of the ISO standard.  That being said, lowercase looks better, views are indivisible, and the number of questions which have mviews are low enough that it doesn't matter.  Lastly, you need only mouse over the number and you'll get a better representation anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A1000000

Comment: @AdamDavis By the time we're done, this will be the most gorgeous bike shed ever. :)

Comment: That's why I'm here!

Answer (score 3):

*First* of all, I think it is rather feature request, than bug.

---

*Second*, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega-)

> Mega is a unit prefix in the metric system denoting a factor of one million (10<sup>6</sup> or 1000000). It was confirmed for use in the [International System of Units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) (SI) in 1960.

I was unable to find [International System of Units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) there unfortunately.

---

*Third*, while they probably should, I don't think it is really important to?

---

*Forth*, it how will it look? Let's see.

[image]
[image]
[image]