# Flag for "official answer" on this and other metas

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, per-site-meta, stack-exchange-team

It would be nice to have a "flag for official answer" on questions on this and other metas for getting the attention of SE employees on [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s where the community has weighed in with their opinions but no official status or comment has been posted.

To avoid everyone flagging for "official answer" on any post, there should be 2 thresholds: one for the time the question has existed (probably > a week to give everyone time to vote and respond), and the other for the popularity of the question. If it has > 1k views, > 30 votes, and no official response, than > 2k users should be able to flag it.

Comment: Related if not a dup of [Can we have a guaranteed pipeline for responses from Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange)

Comment: (Btw, +1 because I'm a user and I like drawing attention to requests, but -1 on the philosophical side because I don't feel we're actually entitled to *anything*, so, net 0 from me. I'm on the fence.)

Comment: The obvious solution here is to just escalate anything that meets those thresholds and not bother with yet another voting system. In theory we already have this; in practice... Well, our workflow kinda sucks, and stacking extra layers on it ain't gonna fix that.

Comment: @Shog9 So the choice is between [status-declined] and keeping this request status-less for irony.

Comment: I'm gonna wait until it hits 1001 views and +31 score, @Gerry. And *then* forget it exists.

Comment: [Here is a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/665859/fr-bug-report-information?MinAgeDays=180&MinScore=0&MinViewCount=1000), for anybody interested, that shows a whole bunch of info for FR and bug reports. See comments, the output can be tweaked to taste. Another interesting query, which I didn't write, would be to count total views and scores not just in FR/bug posts, but also in posts closed as dupes of them (I might do that another time, if anybody else goes for it note that you'll want to collapse the entire dupe graph and not just consider immediate dupes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure where that helps.

In theory, the workflow for a CM here would be roughly akin to a site mod. We use [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review), [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred), [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), and [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) to let people know something is being looked at or sorted out, and we do occationally go "Yeah, this is how we're doing things, for these reasons".

So if it's got appropriate tags, and a appropriate staffer goes "Yeah, this is policy" — it is. In my experience, there's rarely been major ambiguity, and if there is, we know where to ask.