# The "moving comments to chat" feature is too limited

Tags: feature-request, chat

> Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat.
>
> It seems that moving the comments to chat hasn't helped - can you please move some more?
>
> We can only move once. After that, the only way to get them there is for somebody to copy them there one at a time. That's why we just purge new comments that aren't about improving the post.

Given that outright deleting comments ticks people off, and rightly so, how about **improving the move-comments-to-chat feature so that it can be done more than once to the same chat**?

Comment: Indeed it is a duplicate.  But the original was posted four years ago, and despite its popularity, nothing seems to have ever been done about it.

Comment: That is right, the community offers suggestions but SE has no obligation whatsoever to allocate resources to implement those suggestions.

Comment: Or, apparently, even to so much as politely respond about whether they'll implement the feature, and if not, why not.  They could learn something from Slack.

Comment: They could learn so much but I value how they are different. Also related to your "politely respond", that has been politely [status-declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange).

Comment: Wow, that's...wow.  Well, I guess they certainly communicated something there.

Comment: Regarding Slack, though, I've given them feedback from time to time, and they _always_ respond.  Whether it's "That's a great idea, and I'll pass it along" or "That sounds nice, but to be honest, we're not going to do it, and here's why" or "No, this is our new logo, and we're not changing it back."  They _respond_.  I'm OK with being told no.  Of course, I'm also OK with being told yes.  And I'm OK with being told "later" or just "maybe later."  But here on SE I'm nearly always told...*crickets*.  The impression it gives is that frankly, my dear, they don't give a damn.

Comment: Please see [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398) for tips on how to get attention from the team for the older request.

Comment: Here is my take on it: SE is a small company with limited resources (money and people). They simply can't do what other companies do. Instead they choose to focus on delivering value for their customers and to the community as efficiently as possible without having an employee answer thousand of FR's with yes, no, maybe. You're free to not like that or have "impressions" but to call 150+ bloody hard working SE staff that they don't give a damn is plain rude. Harassing SE employees in either comments, chat or the contact us form only makes delivery of all features later, not sooner.

Comment: According to this, [Slack has 800 employees](https://expandedramblings.com/index.php/slack-statistics/).  According to this, [SE has 250+ employees](https://stackoverflow.com/company).  That's a difference, no doubt, but elsewhere it's been calculated that responding to just the truly popular requests would amount to responding to in the neighborhood of [5 requests per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263682/142148).  _Every_ company, no matter its size, has limited resources.  A company shows what it values by how it assigns those resources.